# How to remove the month of the first day in fullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

[image]

As the image shows, how can I remove the month name on the day. Looking for some help. Can't find it in API.

Comment: Documentation shows no sign of removing month name. Why not try set custom empty month names, or make a patch into fullCalendar since its opensource?

Comment: Please give a reference (or snippet or bin) to this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

I removed those pieces of code from fullCalendar.js, found no api option to hide it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14326450)

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to edit the JS. The basic example doesn't show it - https://fullcalendar.io/.

Comment: @rphv this is his answer to his question - he solved it by editing the source (...could only notify one person per comment)